# Caliburn Micro, Message/Action to another ViewModel

Tags: .net, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I got a ShellViewModel with multiple sub views (and viewmodels). A sub view can bind to a method in the ShellViewModel easyly with Message.Attach. It bubbles up. But can I "bubble down" so the ShellViewModel triggers a method in a sub ViewModel or even from one sub view up and then down to another one?

AFAIK I could use EventAggregator but is it the most elegant way?

Comment: you are not suppose to do it. your main view should not know your subviews.

Comment: And how should a toolbar trigger an action in another view which is not above it?

Comment: bind to the same view model / command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, there is no such thing as "bubble down". But, you can use Bind.ModelWithoutContext to move action target to your child ViewModel:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="DoIt" cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding Path=ChildViewModel}" Content="Test It!"/>
```

There is "some" documentation on https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions. Hope it will help you.

Comment: For "just down" this works fine. I guess for more complex scenarios the `EventAggregator` is the way to go. Thanks!